# Intellisense for Vuex Store in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vuejs2, vuex, vetur

I am building an application using [vuejs2](/questions/tagged/vuejs2), [vuex](/questions/tagged/vuex), and [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) in [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code).  I have the [vetur](/questions/tagged/vetur) extension installed. I have built a definition file to give me intellisense for most of my project, but I haven't been able to figure out how to add my [vuex](/questions/tagged/vuex) store to intellisense.  I've read through the [Definition Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html), but I haven't been able to puzzle together how I might do this.  My goal is to be able to get intellisense on anything in `this.$store.`.  Currently, [vetur](/questions/tagged/vetur) provides intellisense for `state`, `getters`, etc. but it does not provide intellisense for the next level (e.g. `this.$store.state.TestVariable`).  How can I get intellisense for my [vuex](/questions/tagged/vuex) store?

#### Contract Management Store

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        Contract: new Library.Model.Entity.Contract()
    }
});
```

#### Contract Component

```
<template>
    <contract-line></contract-line>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import Vuex from 'vuex';
    import store from '../store/ContractManagementStore';
    import ContractLine from "./ContractLine.vue";

    export default Vue.extend({
        name: 'contract-management',
        store,
        components: {
            'contract-line': ContractLine
        }
    });
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

#### Contract Line Component

```
<template>
    <button v-if="CanDelete"></button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import Vuex from 'vuex';

    Vue.use(Vuex);

    export default Vue.extend({
        computed:{
            CanDelete(): Boolean {
                // Looking for intellisense after this.$store.state.
                return this.$store.state.Contract.ContractStatus.Value === Library.Enums.ContractStatus.Draft
            }
        }
    });
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by explicitly typing your state.

In `Contract Management Store.ts`

```
export interface ContractManagementState {
    Contract: ContractType;
}
```

In your Component:

```
...
(this.$store as Store<ContractManagementState>).<intellisense here>
```

You have to do this every time you access the state this way, unfortunately. This is due to the way Vuex uses module augmentation in order to declare the existence of the `$store` property to typescript.

In `vuex/types/vue.d.ts`:

```
declare module "vue/types/vue" {
  interface Vue {
    $store: Store<any>;
  }
}
```

You cannot override the any with your concrete state typings (this is called module *augmentation* after all). A possible solution is to use getters for accessing your Store. Several typescript libraries exist for adding type information to getters, mutators, and actions, such as [vuex-typescript](https://github.com/istrib/vuex-typescript) and [vuex-typex](https://github.com/mrcrowl/vuex-typex).

Comment: I don't think I agree with you about using getters being best practice.  Reading through the [documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html) I see the store being accessed directly consistently for reading data.  I believe the best practice is more focused on modifying data through mutations/actions which I correctly use in my code.  Do you have any Vuex documentation you could point me to about always using getters to access state?

Comment: I'm able to get intellisense for State from this...How would I modify it to also get intellisense for getters/mutators/actions?

Comment: You're absolutely right, there is no recommendation in the Vuex docs explicitly recommending getters over direct state access. I've edited my answer so my opinion doesn't sound like an official recommendation. I still think the points regarding debugging and decoupling are valid though. Also, touching on your second comment, having getters just works better with typescript. I recommend taking a look at the library I posted in the answer, which allows you to type mutators and actions as well (at the cost of some overhead code)

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter this problem these two days, and cannot bear the lack of the typing-awareness of `this.$store.state`.

[@georg-grab 's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50644902/1244729) gives me this inspiration.

> 1. I'm not familiar with TypeScript... So this solution may be silly, but it works.
> 2. My solution can only deal with `this.$store.state`, all others such as `this.$store.dispatch` still has no IntelliSense

```
// store/index.ts
// I will not explain vuex modules here. Please see the doc of Vuex by yourself.
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex, {Store} from 'vuex'

import auth, {State as AuthState} from './modules/auth'  // State is an interface defined in module.

export interface State {
  auth: AuthState
}

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    auth
  }
}) as Store<State>  // Force TypeScript compiler to recognize this as Store<State> instead of Store<any>.
```

Then add a global instance getter via a Vue plugin:

```
// main.ts
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store, { State } from './store'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {  // Tell TypeScript the type of this.$state is our defined 'State'
  interface Vue {
    $state: State
  }
}
const TypedState = {  // define a Vue plugin. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html
  install(Vue: any) {  // For simplify, didn't pass 'State' via options
    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$state', {  // Add a global getter 'this.$state' in vm
      get (): State { return store.state as State }  // Force TypeScript compiler to recognize this as our defined 'State'
    })
  }
}
Vue.use(TypedState)
```

Now you can access the values in `this.$store.state` via `this.$state`, with IntelliSense.

> I also want to "overwrite" the interface of `vm.$store` (from `Store<any>` to `Store<State>`), but TypeScript seems to has no way to do such thing:
>
> ```
> declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
>   interface Vue {
>     $store: Store<State>   // Error
>   }
> }
> ```